# nginx won't start: getpwnam("nginx") failed in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:5

Tags: centos, systemd, nginx, chroot

I am running a chrooted nginx server on CentOS 7. When I try to start nginx, I receive this error: `getpwnam("nginx") failed in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:5`. I have already copied the required libraries, directories (`/etc, /var, /proc, /usr, /lib, /dev`), etc. I am starting the service as root.

My nginx.conf:

```
# For more information on configuration, see:
#   * Official English Documentation: http://nginx.org/en/docs/
#   * Official Russian Documentation: http://nginx.org/ru/docs/
user nginx;
worker_processes auto;
error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

[root@centos user]# nginx -t
nginx: the configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test is successful
```

User/group is present:

```
[root@centos user]# cat /var/www/chroot/etc/passwd | grep nginx
nginx:x:993:988:Nginx web server:/var/lib/nginx:/bin/bash

[root@centos user]# cat /var/www/chroot/etc/group | grep nginx
nginx:x:988:
```

Also, my custom nginx.service file:

```
[Unit]
Description=A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server in a 
chroot jail
After=syslog.target network.target

[Service]
Type=forking
RootDirectory=/var/www/chroot
PIDFile=/var/www/chroot/run/nginx.pid
ExecStartPre=/usr/sbin/chroot /var/www/chroot /usr/sbin/nginx -t -q -g 'pid 
/run/nginx.pid; daemon on; master_process on;'
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/chroot /var/www/chroot /usr/sbin/nginx -g 'pid 
/run/nginx.pid; daemon on; master_process on;'
ExecReload=/usr/sbin/chroot /var/www/chroot /usr/sbin/nginx -g 'pid 
/run/nginx.pid; daemon on; master_process on;' -s reload
ExecStop=/usr/sbin/chroot /var/www/chroot /usr/sbin/nginx -g 'pid 
/run/nginx.pid;' -s quit
RootDirectoryStartOnly=yes

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

nginx version:

```
[root@centos user]# yum info nginx
Installed Packages
Name        : nginx
Arch        : x86_64
Epoch       : 1
Version     : 1.10.2
Release     : 1.el7
```

Comment: you need a minimal copy of /etc/passwd in the chroot, at least with the nginx user

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro As I stated above, I have already copied all of the relevant directories and files: `[root@centos /]# cat /var/www/chroot/etc/passwd | grep nginx` ->
 `nginx:x:993:988:Nginx web server:/var/lib/nginx:/bin/bash`.

Comment: To be fair, you demonstrated `cat /etc/passwd `, not the chroot path.

Comment: @JeffSchaller fair point.

Comment: `getpwnam(3)` and friends use nsswitch to get the actual data.  nsswitch supports different data sources implemented as modules (libraries loaded through `dlopen(3)`).  You need to have both `nsswitch.conf` and the selected modules available in your `chroot` environment: Check the `passwd` field in `nsswitch.conf` and make sure you have the corresponding module in your `chroot` (e.g. `/lib/libnss_files-X.XX.so`).

Comment: @AndreasWiese, this solved the issue. After checking the `passwd` field in `/path/to/chroot/etc/nsswitch.conf`, I saw `passwd: files sss`. I added the corresponding `libnss_files-2.17.so` and `libnss_files.so.2` modules to the `chroot` and the error went away. Do you know of any more in depth documentation or reading (besides manpages) describing this in more detail to better my understanding?